# $\mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y=z]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ be random variables such that $X\overset{\underset{d}{}}{=}\mathcal{P}\left(\lambda_{1}\right)$ and $Y\overset{\underset{d}{}}{=}\mathcal{P}\left(\lambda_{2}\right)$. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y=z]$, where $z$ is a non-negative integer.

Attempt:

$X+Y\overset{\underset{d}{}}{=}\mathcal{P}\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right)$, so

\begin{align*}
        p_{Y|X+Y}(y|z)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\mathbb{P}(X=z-y)}{\mathbb{P}(X+Y=z)}\\
        &=\binom{z}{x}\left ( \frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}} \right )^{x}\left ( \frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}} \right )^{z-x}.
    \end{align*}

Therefore, $Y\mid X+Y\overset{\underset{d}{}}{=}\text{Bin}\left(z,\frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}\right)$ and

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y=z]=\frac{z\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{1}},\text{ }\forall z\in\mathbb{N}_{0}.$$

Comment: Does $\mathcal{P}$ mean Poisson?

Comment: Yes it does @Henry

Comment: You might edit that into the question.  You also probably have a typo in "therefore $X+Y\overset{\underset{d}{}}{=}\text{Bin}\left(z,\frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}\right)$" since you earlier said "$X+Y\overset{\underset{d}{}}{=}\mathcal{P}\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right)$", and  earlier you used $x$ instead of $y$. I suspect your final result of $\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2} z$ is correct as well as being intuitively attractive

Comment: Also this assumes that $X, Y$ are independent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything checks out save the typographic error: you jumped from an expression in $y$ to an expression in $x$.

---

$X+Y\overset{\small d}{=}\mathcal{P}\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}\right)$, so

\begin{align*}
        p_{Y|X+Y}(y|z)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y=y)\mathbb{P}(X=z-y)}{\mathbb{P}(X+Y=z)}\\
        &=\binom{z}{\color{red}y}\left ( \frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}} \right )^{\color{red}y}\left ( \frac{\lambda_{1}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}} \right )^{z-\color{red}y}.
    \end{align*}

Therefore, $\color{red}{Y\mid }X+Y\color{red}{{=}z}~\overset{\small{d}}{=}~\mathcal{Bin}\left(z,\frac{\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}}\right)$ and

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y=z]=\frac{z\lambda_{2}}{\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{1}},\text{ }\forall z\in\mathbb{N}_{0}.$$

Comment: Independence of $X,Y$ is an assumption that needs to be stated in the question.

Comment: Ah, yes, there is that.